# How can I make RobotFramework interact with Select2/JQuery elements?

Tags: jquery, python, pycharm, robotframework, jquery-select2

I can't seem to figure out how to gather xpath or Id values from Select2 elements. I'm currently using Select2 to manage and populate drop-down lists and text boxes. I can only seem to get the locator values of the initial Select2 element, while being unable to get something for any of the items within its drop-down list.

I need assistance finding a way to input text into the Select2 drop down, then verify the correct items are displayed on search; e.g  Searching NJ (how its stored in the backend) and displaying New Jersey (as its saved in the Select2 element). As well as actually selecting and interacting with said option/element.

Comment: Do you have any specific code examples of what you've tried but didn't work? Right now it's too generic to provide you with any kind of solution approach.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I can't start any code examples, since I can't pull any sort of locator. I first need a way to get xpath, Css, or Id selectors from Select2's elements. If I can get those selectors, then potentially I can have Robot Framework interact with it directly like it should. Otherwise I can jankly wire in JQuery or something to interact with it within the Robot Framework test, but that's a bridge to cross later. Right now I just need a way to get the selector method that robot framework / python will accept.

Comment: On the Select2 site there are some examples: https://select2.github.io/examples.html. Have you tried those?